# custom phone number formatting

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In my `Android` application I want create my own phone number formatting but still couldn't find a way to do this.

I read about phone number libs and so on but still couldn't find a way to do this because all libs is working fine with `US`, `German`, `French` and other formats. I want to support `Russian` and these libs doesn't work fine.

The only way is I have to create my own formatting.

for example if I type

```
79123456789
```

it have to be formatted like in here

```
+7(912)345-67-89
```

I found libs for `IOS` (SHSPhoneTextField) but in `Android` I didn't.

Could anyone just tell me good solution in here?

```
  mPhoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                if (charSequence.length() == 11)
                mPhoneNumber.setText(PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(charSequence.toString()));
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: is this the only format you want?

Comment: You code has a forever loop. The listener calls setText() and the setText() calls listener...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help (PhoneNumberUtils): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html

A little example:

```
String formattedNumber = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(unformattedNumber);
```

This will automatically format the number according to the rules for the country the number is from.

Look at PhoneNumberUtils for more options.

Comment: Could you place your code? We can't help you if we don't see your code. The code I placed is an example. It could be possible that it isn't working, but you can find out on the website I give you how you can make it work.

Comment: @pmb And what does logcat say? Is the code triggered or not? Have you tested it correctly with your debug? Have you tried writing the format to the console so that you know the code is triggered?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47866/discussion-between-pmb-and-p-griep)

Answer (score 0):

You shoul use `PhoneNumberUtils` with the desired `Locale` like this:

```
Locale localeRU = new Locale("ru","RU");
String formattedNumber = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(unformattedNumber, PhoneNumberUtils.getFormatTypeForLocale (localeRU));
```

Have a look for the appropriate `Locale` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html).

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
  if (charSequence.length() == 11)     
     Locale localeRU = new Locale("ru","RU");
     mPhoneNumber.setText(PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(charSequence.toString(), localeRU));
  }
```

Comment: what is unformattedNumber? I just change it my phone number and there is error.

Comment: In your case its charSequence.toString()

Comment: no it requires a string, please be more specific, what kind of problem you have

Comment: look here public static void formatNumber(android.text.Editable text, int defaultFormattingType) { /* compiled code */ }

Comment: I added another example above

Comment: formatting called but it doesn't format correctly for russian

Comment: What is the output? Waht kind of formatting was used?

Comment: for example when I type 79000000000 it the result is same, but when I use Locale.US it works fine